# Custom inline role for hyperlinks in Docutils/Sphinx

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, docutils

I would like to define a special class of hyperlinks.

For regular text span, this would be done by defining and using a custom role like this:

```
.. role:: myrole

This is :myrole:`whatever`.
```

which then appears as `<span class="myrole">whatever</span>` in HTML and as  `\DUrole{myrole}{whatever}` in LaTeX (as [documented](http://www.docutils.org/docs/user/latex.html#custom-interpreted-text-roles)).

Is there a way to do the same for hyperlinks, so that I get `\DUrole{myrole}{\sphinxhref{target}{text}}` in LaTeX?

The issue is, hyperlinks don't seem to have a named role (so that one could define inherited role `.. role:: myhyper(hyperlink)`) and can only be created with backticks:

```
`text <target>__`
```

which can't be nested in another role's parameter because of the backticks.

(There is a way to create those with MyST parser and `attrs_inline` extension as `[text](target){.myhyper}`, but it only works with the HTML writer and does not get exported into LaTeX.)